# jquery action for all input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't know how to phrase this to search the web for the answer.

Is it possible to assign a blur action to all inputs that are of type "text"?  I have a form with 60 or so input controls.  I'd like to have a blur action on all of them (to uppercase) without having to write a blur for each and every one of them.

Comment: See this simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bsLu0a9j/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by doing:

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
  // your code here
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: How would I identify the specific input to switch the case to upper?  "this"?  (sorry, should have been more specific in my question)

Comment: Btw, if you're doing only that, I suggest you to use the `input` event, it's better.

Comment: `$('input[type=text]').on('input',function(){this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();});`

Comment: And if you're doing that only for design reasons, you can even use CSS for that: `input[type=text] { text-transform: uppercase; }`

Comment: Sweet.  You rock, dude.  I like the CSS solution better than the jquery one, actually.

Comment: @Buzinas Does the CSS method really modify the input value, or just change how it's displayed?

Comment: @Barmar only change how it's displayed. That's why I said "if you're doing that only for design reasons".

Comment: "design" is a pretty general term. I'm not sure the OP may have understood the ramifications.

Comment: Which works for me.  I'm replicating a PDF form that the users download and fill out, but can be filled out in the field in html then sent to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function(){

// your code here

});
```